# C# What is the difference between Text.Encoder and Text.Encoding

Tags: c#, unicode, encoding, encoder

I am currently using Unicode in bytes and using Encoding class to get bytes and get strings.

However, I saw there is an encoder class and it seems like doing the same thing as the encoding class. Does anyone know what is the difference between them and when to use either of them.

Here are the Microsoft documentation page:

Encoder: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoder(v=vs.110).aspx

Encoding: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Nothing.  Looks like documentation for different versions of Net Libraries, but basically the same info.

Comment: These classes have coexisted since the early days of .Net (probably since the first version) as part of the framework.

Comment: This is a really good question, and I'm surprised this hasn't been asked before.  Or my Google-fu isn't strong enough.

Comment: There is some useful information on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.getencoder(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: There is also System.Text.Decoder, important to fill the picture.  They each do half of the job that Encoding does.

Answer (score 9):

There is definitely a difference. An `Encoding` is an algorithm for transforming a sequence of characters into bytes and vice versa. An `Encoder` is a stateful object that transforms sequences of characters into bytes. To get an `Encoder` object you usually call `GetEncoder` on an Encoding object. Why is it necessary to have a stateful tranformation? Imagine you are trying to efficiently encode long sequences of characters. You want to avoid creating a lot of arrays or one huge array. So you break the characters down into say reusable 1K character buffers. However this might make some illegal characters sequences, for example a utf-16 surrogate pair broken across to separate calls to `GetBytes`. The `Encoder` object knows how to handle this and saves the necessary state across successive calls to `GetBytes`. Thus you use an `Encoder` for transforming one block of text that is self-contained. I believe you can reuse an Encoder instance more transforms of multiple sections of text as long as you have called GetBytes with `flush` equal to true on the last array of characters. If you just want to easily encode short strings, use the `Encoding.GetBytes` methods. For the decoding operations there is a similar Decoder class that holds the decoding state.

Comment: In other words, an Encod**ER** creates and Encod**ING**

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch other way around, an Encoding creates Encoders.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Thanks a lot, because no one has asked this question before. Correct me if I am wrong please, "Encoding" encodes / decodes the characters in one time. "Encoder" encodes / decodes the characters by separating them into blocks, therefore it can process a much longer list of characters as a continues operation.